# Keep pointers between class members stable when moving

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Suppose a class *C* has two members, *M1* and *M2*, where *M1* holds a pointer *P* that refers to *M2*.
For every instance *X* of *C* the following invariant should hold: *X.M1.P* points to *X.M2*.

Is there an idiomatic way to implement this behaviour in C++ without having to implement a move constructor and assignment operator?

I'm asking because it seems to me that conceptually the pointer *P* should be relative to *M1*. Non-default move constructors and assignment operators seem like lots of work (especially if there are a few members) for this simple concept.

My specific use-case is similar to the example below (where `set` is *M1*, and `less` is *M2*). Perhaps my fundamental approach is flawed — is there a better way than having a pointer to `Relation` in `Less`?

```
using Relation = std::vector<std::vector<bool>>;

class C {
 public:
  C() { /* less = ...; */ }
  C(C&&) = default;
  C& operator=(C&&) = default;

 private:
  struct Less {
    explicit Less(const Relation* r) : r(r) {}
    bool operator()(int i, int j) { return (*r)[i][j]; }
    const Relation* r;
  };

  Relation less;
  std::set<int, Less> set{Less(&less)};
};

C a;
std::cout << a.set.key_comp().r == &a.less << std::endl; // true
C b = std::move(a);
std::cout << b.set.key_comp().r == &b.less << std::endl; // false
```

Comment: You need to actually write your own move constructor and assignment operator, that initializes the `set` member correctly (with the correct pointer for the `Less` structure).

Comment: I'd rather do without custom move ctor/operator. Just realized, a concise solution would be to have a `std::unique_ptr<Relation> less` instead of `Relation less` and hand `less.get()` to the `std::set`.

Comment: Why not store the `Relation` *inside* the `Less` object?  `C` could easily access it via the very `key_comp` call you’re showing.

Comment: @DavisHerring Good idea, I totally missed that. However, `Less` would become a heavy-weight. Functors like this are generally assumed to be efficiently copyable, aren't they?

Comment: It's a possible solution. But I personally dislike it since it breaks the ownership-semantics of the smart pointers, as well as my personal belief that pointers should be avoided as much as possible. With "proper" constructors and assignment operators you could use references instead, for example.

Comment: @chs: Are you going to copy the `set` *other* than when copying the `C`?  If so, you could always put a `std::shared_ptr<Relation>` in the `Less` instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agreed, if the class had only a couple of members, I'd do that, but with several members that adds many lines to maintain for to express such a simple concept. (Splitting up the class into multiple ones in a reasonable way is difficult because it implements an algorithm where the variables are all very closely related to each other.)

Comment: @DavisHerring Nope, neither `set` nor `C` is copied at all actually, they're only moved altogether.